# MXF files in Premiere Pro cs5 mac only playing/dispaying audio

Tags: premiere, cs5

Hi I'm having issues with my MXF files in Premiere Pro cs5. When I bring my mxf files into my project its only playing back audio, i can't even see video. It's like its only reading it as audio.

If I play the mxf file outside of Preimere in VLC I am able to see the video and audio.

Is there an extension I need or something?

Premiere Pro cs5
Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.2 
Shot on Cannon c300

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you could also try an intermediate workflow, like transcoding the MXF files into an appropriate ProRes container. This most likely would be 422Proxy.

The Canon C300 codec is a variation of XDCAM (source: http://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/editing-with-canon-c300-footage-tips-for-when-it-all-goes-wrong/) I personally do not like to edit in Long-GOP or predictive frame codecs. So transcoding to an inter-frame codec like ProRes or DNX is always a safe bet.

Comment: Just a clarification: inter-frame codecs use predictive frames. Apple ProRes, MJPEG and the Avid DNx family of codecs are intra-frame codecs, where each frame is coded independently of others.

Answer (score 0):

This is a know bug of adobe premiere pro

See:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1022632?tstart=0

Workarounds:

1) Use the Canon XF Utility to create a single MXF file of your spanned clips.
Import the new file into the project.

2)
The problem you are facing is that you are probably just copying a single subclip over.
What you need to do is copy the WHOLE folder over.
Then use the media browser to find the clip.
Then import it into your premiere pro and that should work.